# Uploading image to blob container is having zero bytes

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload image to blob container from asp.net core, but i see that image is zero bytes afer uploading image in blob container. i search in google to resolve the issue and set position=0 even though still issue exists, does any one find me solution where am i wrong.

Here is code i am using.

```
   public async Task AddFace(IFormFile file)
    {
        dynamic FileExtension = string.Empty;
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileExtension))
            {
                FileExtension = ".jpg";
            }
            using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                   

                //UPLOAD TO BLOB CONTAINER
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(configuration[ConfigKeys.BlobStorageConfiguration.BlobContainer]);
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName+FileExtension );

        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: I resolved this issue when i set stream.position=0. thanks for all